# Automatic scrolling when clicking my submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So on my custom module that I've created, there's a submit button (form defined in php) but it already acquires an action where it calls a callback function to trigger the display of some information regarding a certain barcode right below it.

All I want to do is add some code that will allow my submit button to also trigger an automatic scroll down without a link/anchor (because I want the SUBMIT BUTTON to acquire that action, not another link) so that the user doesn't have to scroll down to view the information.

The reason I'm avoiding the link/anchor option is because I just dont want to have a separate entity that needs to be clicked in order to scroll down. I want the scroll to happen right when i click my submit button. Unless a link can be combined with a button? Thanks!

My PHP submit button form:

```
//submit button that uses ajax (to display whats in callback)
$form['submit_button'] = array(
            '#type'=> 'submit',
            '#value'=> t('Submit'),
            '#ajax' => array( //no need to refresh the page bc ajax
                    'callback' => '_ibbr_inv_after_callback', //callback
            ),
            '#suffix' => "<div id='after_div'><br></div>
                      <div id='after_status'></div>",
    );
    return $form;
```

My PHP callback function:

```
//function for submit button callback
function _ibbr_inv_after_callback($form, $form_state) {
    $selector = '#after_div';
    $commands = array();

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'eq')
    ->propertyCondition('title', $form_state['input']['barcode'])
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->range(0,1)
    ->execute();

    //If this barcode is found in database
    if (!empty($entities['node'])) {
            $node = node_load(array_shift(array_keys($entities['node'])));

            //Load fields from returned equipment item
            $room = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_eq_room['und'][0]['tid']);
            $desc = $node->field_eq_description['und'][0]['value'];
            $manu =  $node->field_eq_mfr['und'][0]['value'];
            $model = $node->field_eq_modelno['und'][0]['value'];
            $serial = $node->field_eq_serial['und'][0]['value'];
            //displaying all the components of the specific barcode
            $info = "<div id='after_div'><b>Title</b>: $node->title<br>
                            <b>Description</b>: $desc<br>
                            <b>Manufacturer</b>: $manu<br>
                            <b>Room</b>: $room->name<br>
                            <b>Model Number:</b> $model<br>
                            <b>Serial Number:</b> $serial<br></div>";
            //Displaying the Confirm and Flag buttons
            $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector,  $info);
            $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#after_status", "<div id='after_status'> <button id = 'confirm' type = 'submit' name = 'Confirm' value = 'Confirm'> Confirm</button><button id = 'Flag' type = 'submit' name = 'flag' value = 'flag'>Flag </button> </div>");
            //$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke("#after_div", 'animate', array("{scrollTop: top}",1000));
    //If this barcode is not found in the database
    }else {
            //Displaying the Add button and "Item not found" ONLY IF this entity is empty (meaning barcode was not found in database)
            $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector,  "<div id = 'after_div'>Item not found.</div>");
            $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#after_status", "<div id='after_status'><button id = 'add' type = 'submit' name = 'Add' value = 'Add'>Add new item</button></div>");

    }
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}//end _ibbr_inv_after_callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript you can make your submit button to jump to any HTML element on the page, without link/anchor. Next example has two buttons, when clicked, buttons will scroll down to different points of the page :

```
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function godown ()
{ document.getElementById("down").scrollIntoView(); // JUMP TO DIV "DOWN".
}
function gobottom ()
{ document.getElementById("bottom").scrollIntoView(); // JUMP TO DIV "BOTTOM".
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="godown()">Click to go down</button>
    <button onclick="gobottom()">Click to go bottom</button>

    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>
    <br/>1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>0<br/>

    <div id="down">You are down!</div>

    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>
    <br/>a<br/>b<br/>c<br/>d<br/>e<br/>f<br/>g<br/>h<br/>i<br/>j<br/>

    <div id="bottom">You are at the bottom!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You just insert your information inside a `<div>` (or a table, or anything you want), give it an "id", and you will be able to scroll down to it with javascript method ".scrollIntoView()".

Copy/paste previous code in a file and save it as HTML, then open it in your browser.

Edit #1 : add some javascript code with PHP right after you fill "after_div" :

```
 $info = "<div id='after_div'><b>Title</b>: $node->title<br>
                            <b>Description</b>: $desc<br>
                            <b>Manufacturer</b>: $manu<br>
                            <b>Room</b>: $room->name<br>
                            <b>Model Number:</b> $model<br>
                            <b>Serial Number:</b> $serial<br></div>" .
         "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
         "document.getElementById('after_div').scrollIntoView();" . 
         "</script>";
```

Edit #2 : replace this line :

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector,  "<div id = 'after_div'>Item not found.</div>");
```

by this next one :

```
$body = "<div id = 'after_div'>Item not found.</div>" .
         "<script type='text/javascript'>" .
         "document.getElementById('after_div').scrollIntoView();" . 
         "</script>";
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace($selector,  $body);
```

Comment: Yeah I did that, but it doesnt work... I put it in my  ajax command replace but it doesnt work. I dont know where to insert it so that it scrolls down to "Item not found" -- which by the way also has an id of after_div

Comment: Oh i see what you did, because since we had to add this new JS code, you had to make a new variable and pass that all in as the parameter instead! duh. Thanks Jose!!